# Zsh: Why is \n interpreted within single quotes?

Tags: zsh

From my understanding, a `\n` should be interpreted as a new line in

```
"a\nb"
$'a\nb'
```

but not in

```
'a\nb'
```

However, I see the following:

*(transscript from my zsh session follows)*

```
-0-1- ~  > zsh --version
zsh 5.1.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)
-0-1- ~  > echo 'a\nb'
a
b
-0-1- ~  >
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`zsh` itself does not interpret the `\n` in `'a\nb'`, but the builtin `echo` does. `'a\nb'` and `"a\nb"` are equivalent and do not contain a newline but the (literal) character sequence `\n`. `$'a\nb'` on the other hand actually does contains a newline.

There are two things at work here:

#### 1. Quoting:

Quoting is used to tell the shell that you want a character itself, not any special meaning it may have in the shells syntax. `zsh` has four types of quoting, some of which may retain or add special meaning to a few characters or character sequences:

1. `\`: Quoting of single characters by prepending `\`. For `zsh` saying `\n` only means "I want the character `n`". As `n` has no special meaning, it is the same as writing just `n`. This changes with characters like `*`: Without quoting `*` is used as a wildcard for globbing, writing `\*` prevents that (for example: compare outputs of `echo /*` and `echo /\*`). If you want to pass the character `\` literally, you have to quote it, for example with another `\`: `\\`.
2. `'...'`: Just like with `\` any character withing `'...'` is taken literally, this includes other methods of quoting. `'foo* bar?'` is essentially equivalent to `foo\*\ bar\?` (or `\f\o\o\*\ \b\a\r\?` if one wants to be pedantic). Only `'` itself cannot appear inside a string quoted with `'...'` as it would mark the end of the qoute. (This can be changed by setting `RC_QUOTES`. If set a pair of single quote is taken as a single quote: `'foo''bar'` → `foo\'bar`)
3. `"..."`: Allows for parameter and command substitution. That means words after a `$` are taken as parameter names (e.g. `"path: $PATH"`) and strings wrapped in `$(...)` or `` `...` `` are used for command substitution (e.g. `echo "Date: $(date)"`). Otherwise it behaves like `'...'` with the exception that it allows the quoting of `` ` ``, `$`, `\` and `"` with `\`.
4. `$'...'`: strings insid `$'...'` are treated like string arguments of the `print` builtin. Only here some alphabetic characters have indeed special meaning: `\n` for newline, `\b` for backspace, `\a` for the bell character, etc.. `\` and `'` can be quoted with `\\` and `\'` respectively. The resulting string is considered fully quoted. There is *no* parameter or command substitution inside `$'...'`.

#### 2. The zsh-builtin `echo`:

Other than the `echo` binary or the bash-builtin `echo` the zsh-builtin by default recognizes (some) escape sequences like `\n` or `\t`. While this behavior usually needs to be explicitly enabled with `/bin/echo` or the bash-builtin (usually by passing the `-e` flag: `echo -e "foo\nbar"`), for the zsh-builtin it need to be explicitly disabled. Either by passing the `-E` flag (`echo -E 'foo\nbar'`) or by setting the `BSD_ECHO` option (`setopt bsdecho`) in which case the `-e` flag can be used to re-enable the feature like with the other types of `echo`.

#### Conclusion

That means that both `'a\nb'` and `"a\nb"` (and `a\\nb` for that matter) are passed as `a\nb` (literally), but the zsh-builtin `echo` then interprets the `\n`, leading to an output with a newline. On the other hand `$'a\nb'` contains a literal newline already before it is passed to `echo`.

Running

```sh
for quoted_string in a\\nb 'a\nb' "a\nb" $'a\nb'; do
    echo '>' $quoted_string '<'
    /bin/echo -e '>' $quoted_string '<'
    echo -E '>' $quoted_string '<'
    /bin/echo '>' $quoted_string '<'
    echo
done
```

should get you the following output:

```sh
> a
b <
> a
b <
> a\nb <
> a\nb <

> a
b <
> a
b <
> a\nb <
> a\nb <

> a
b <
> a
b <
> a\nb <
> a\nb <

> a
b <
> a
b <
> a
b <
> a
b <
```

As you can see there is no difference between the first three kinds of quoting, while the fourth always prints with a newline.

---

BTW: `perl` (at least version 5; I do not know about Perl 6) behaves in the way you describe the expected behavior. In `perl` `'...'` behaves like it does in `zsh`. On the other hand`"..."` in `perl` behaves like a combination of `"..."` and `$'...'` of `zsh`: variables are replaced by their value and character sequences like `\n` and `\t` are treated specially.

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong about `"a\nb"`, which does **not** replace `\n` with a newline (well, not portably, anyway). So there is no standard quoting mechanism that allows a newline in a string without using a literal newline, as in

```
x="a
b"
```

This is why the `$'a\nb'` notation was invented to do just that. It's not POSIX as of 2016, but the POSIX folks are thinking about adding it to the [shell specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html). As always, don't hold your breath :-)

Comment: Note that in the original question, `'a\nb'` and `"a\nb"` are both 4-character strings; `zsh`'s implemenation of `echo` recognizes the digraph `\n` and outputs a newline character in its place.

Comment: @chepner Are you sure? My zsh (5.2) with `echo "a\nb"` echoes `a\nb` (I have bsdecho set).

Comment: Yes; `bsdecho` is the option that explicitly disables the (POSIX-specified) interpretation of the escaped characters.

Answer (score 0):

A new line is a character, not a variable, so there is no interpretation (or expansion). If you want to print a `\`, you need to escape it twice to indicate that you don’t want to escape a variable *and* that you don’t want to print a special character.

So you have to use `echo a\\\\nb` or `echo 'a\\nb'`